# How to centre a absolute div

Tags: html, css, position, tailwind-css

I want to have control over a div when I make it absolute

I tried making it left 30% right 30% then I gave top a particular pixel when it get to where I want to be it becomes squished what should I do because I want to give it a max-width

Answer (score -1):

```css
.absolute-div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  top: 100px; /* Adjust the top position as needed */
  max-width: 500px; /* Adjust the maximum width as needed */
}
```

This will center the absolute div horizontally within its container and give it a maximum width, preventing it from becoming squished when the viewport width changes. You can adjust the values for top and max-width to suit your design requirements.

Answer (score -1):

To center this div horizontally, try this:

```css
position: absolute;
margin: 0 auto;
top:100px //or whatever;
```